Routes in Azure Function app .NET 8 Isolated with project references
Running .NET 8 isolated project with multiple Azure Function apps, each containing dozens of endpoints/functions.
If FuncApp1 references FuncApp2, then the routes from FuncApp2 show up when you run FuncApp1.
I want to be able to access models and services from FuncApp2 from within FuncApp1 without loading all of it's routes.
Is there a way to disable loading the routes from FuncApp2 when running FuncApp1 without removing the project reference, or custom defining the route table?
Possibly dynamically disabling routes that have been automatically indexed at start up, or a property for the project reference that would disable indexing the project for endpoints?
Requirements, ability to dynamically choose or exclude routes at run time or start up.
I have researched and reviewed many different options but have yet to find one that fits what I'm looking for, I simply want to disable the routes coming from the referenced project, so that the first app only contains the endpoint routes from itself, even if it references another Azure Function app.
